# echo alphabet options without writing each letter as array element?

Tags: php, arrays

```html
<select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    //...  and so on - till Z
</select>
```

is there any shorter way, something like:

```
$arr = alphabet;
foreach($arr as $el){
    echo "<option>" . $el . "</option>";
}
```

So, I need to avoid writing this:

```
$arr = array('A','B','C','D'... );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `range()` with the limits `A` and `Z`. This creates the array with the characters defined in that range. Then all you need is to loop over it and print it!

```php
<select>
<?php
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $l) {
    echo '<option value="'.$l.'">'.$l."</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
```

If you want to add other letters than A-Z, you are probably better off adding those manually - `range()` doesn't like characters outside the *range* of A-Z.

```php
<select>
<?php
$alphabet = range('A', 'Z');
$alphabet[] = 'č';
$alphabet[] = 'ć';
$alphabet[] = 'š';
$alphabet[] = 'đ';
$alphabet[] = 'ž'; 
foreach ($alphabet as $l) {
    echo '<option value="'.$l.'">'.$l."</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use [range](https://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) "Create an array containing a range of elements":

```
$arr = range('A','Z');
foreach($arr as $el){
    echo "<option>" . $el . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's it. Maybe options for other languages?

Comment: What do you mean by "other languages"? Java, python, .., or greek, russian, ... ?

Comment: croatian, in my case - having čćšđž

Comment: I guess you will need to manually set all letters, or use some 3rd party library. If you just append an array with this letters ou will lose the "correct" order.

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330383/sort-array-of-words-non-english-letters-double-character-letters-php

Answer (score 3):

The others have shown `range`, but to get rid of the loop:

```
echo '<option>'.implode('</option><option>', range('A', 'Z')).'</option>';
```